# I am trying to use split function to split a string after - but it is ignoring the negative numbers

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string which I want to split into `result` items

```
string operatingwt = "Description 2--340-20"
```

I am trying to split it by `-` and get the `result` as

```
Description 2
-340 // <- Note, that '-' is a part of item 
20
```

But when I try to split with a help of `operatingwt.Split('-');`
I get the output as

```
Description 2
               // <- Unwanted empty string
340            // <- absence of - here (340 instead of -340)
20
```

Comment: you need to replace `--` into `$-` first, then split by `-`, then replace every element's `$` into `-`. If there is `$` in your data, you can use other symbols instead.

Comment: @user16606026 if you have the _answer_, why _comment_?

Comment: Sai: how much power do you have on the formatting of the input string? Can you demand it be changed to something that makes a little more sense?

Comment: I do not have much power on the formatting of the input string.

Comment: @user16606026: in *general case*, changing like this doesn't work: `123$-456--789` should be processed into `{"123$", "-456", "-789"}`. If we change `--` into `$-` and then split the original `$` will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated your input this may or may not work:

```
string s = "Description 2--340-20";

s = s.Replace("-", ";").Replace(";;", ";-");

var elements = s.Split(';');
```

Depending on the input the following could work better:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string s = "Description 2--340-20";

// "([^-])-" means "match any character that is not a dash, followed by a dash". Please also catch the first character in the group so that we can insert it back using "$1" in the replacement string.
s = Regex.Replace(s, "([^-])-", "$1;"); // -> Description 2;-340;20

var elements = s.Split(';');
```

Comment: Changing `-` into `;` can lead to problems (unwanted splits) in *general case*: `123;456--789` should be splitted into `{ "123;456", "-789" }`. If change `-` into `;` and then split, we'll an extra split `{"123", "456", "-789"}`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a more flexible [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-8.0) instead of `String.Replace`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string operatingwt = "Description 2--340-20";

var result = Regex.Split(operatingwt, "(?<!-)-");
```

Here we split on `-` if it doesn't have another `-` before it (i.e. having consequent `-` we split by the *first one only*).

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
Description 2
-340
20
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nw7FZ5)

Comment:  "lookbehind zero-length assertion"

Answer (score 0):

If you are only taking word characters into account, you might split on matching a hyphen `-` preceded by a word boundary `\b` keeping a leading hyphen for a negative value:

```
\b-
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CXVl6I/1).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest regular expression pattern:

```
var operatingwt = "Description 2--340-20";
var r = new Regex(@"-(?=-\d)|(?<=[^-])-(?=[^-])");
```

Then the line `r.Split(operatingwt);` gives the following output:
[image]

**Pattern explanation**:

`-` - match `-` literally,

`(?=-\d)` - assure that what follow is `-` followed by digit,

`|` - alternation,

`(?<=[^-])` - assure that what preceeds is NOT hyphen, due to negated character class `[^-]`

`-` - match `-` literally,

`(?=[^-])` - assure that what follows is NOT hyphen, due to negated character class `[^-]`